# Create XML file from string (in cells) with excel

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I've made an excel file that creates xml statements. I would like to make a macro that creates an xml file and fills it with the xml statement that already exists as a string.

Additional background info: My excel file creates xml statements with concatenates. So far I was just copying the value of the cell and it worked just fine but because of the 34k character limit I need to divide my formula into 6-7 cells. I thought it would be good to make a macro not to have to copy/paste 7 times.

Thanks,
JG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you already have a string with the data you need to write, then an `open ... print ... close` would work.

e.g.

```
Open "C;\MyPath\MyFile.xml" For Output As #1
print #1, DataString
Close #1
```

If you search help for `Open`, then you would need to look at the **vba** version: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264163%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

If you want to do something more fancy, then looking at the file system object: fso on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278516%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Sean! It works fine and is very simple! Cheers